# Update a particular row in a database when a particular button is clicked. php

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

Okay so for instance say I have a site where users can vote on polls.

And lets say that each poll is in the database, and each poll has a unique ID column, as well as a column that stores the question, a column for how many votes yes, and a column for how many votes no.

And lets say I have a page where users can go to view polls. So I query the database for all the polls and then loop through them all, printing them to the screen, as well as placing a radio button form next to each one, where you can vote yes/no on the question and then submit.

This is where I need help. If I have, say, hundreds of these polls on the screen, and a user clicks the submit button next to just one, and votes, how can I identify which unique poll I need to update the records for?

So I guess what I'm saying is, how do I associate each poll's id, to its own submit button, so that when a user clicks that specific submit button, I know which poll to update the records for?

```
Database: A_Database

Table: Polls
ID        Question           Yes    No
1       "Is the sky blue?"    0     0
2       "Is water wet?"       0     0
```

This is the structure of the database. So now I will query all the questions, and print them to the screen as well as a form to submit a vote.

```
$query = SELECT * FROM `Polls`;
   if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
        $count = 0;
        $array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run);
        while ($count < mysql_num_rows($query_run)) {
            echo '<strong>Poll: Yes/No:</strong>'.'<br>';
            echo mysql_result($query_run, $count, 'Question').' ';
            echo mysql_result($query_run, $count, 'yes').'/';
            echo mysql_result($query_run, $count, 'no').' ';
                            echo '<form><input type="radio" name="vote"> yes
                                        <input type="radio" name="vote"> no 
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="vote">
                                  </form>';
            $count = $count + 1;
        }
    } else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
```

Okay, so now all the polls are outputted to the screen, and each has a submit button next to it. My question is how can I associate each submit button to its own poll, so that when a user votes and clicks a particular submit button, I know which poll to update the records for.

Comment: you need to provide more details if someone is going to be able to help you. What is the structure of the database? etc...

Comment: Alright i added some code. I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like foreach poll, use a unique ID. Using jQuery, when the uniqueID submit button is clicked, send an ajax POST request to update the database and then update the poll data on the screen on success.

Unless you show your work, I can't give you any specific information beyond how it sounds like I would be doing it given your description.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, any way this can be done only using PHP? Im afraid im not familiar with JQuery. I added some more info so i hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Updating a row in a database is **impossible** to do with just php. You would have to use Javascript.

PHP is a *server side* language and Javascript is a *client side* language.

This means that the server renders the html page for your browser to print using PHP, before your web browser gets a chance to see it. A database cannot be modified with PHP, unless the server loads up the whole page again, as the *server side* language runs first.

This is why you would have to use Javascript for this. As Javascript is a *client side* language, it runs in the confines of the web browser. Because of this, you would then be able to update the database if you use Javascript.

This Javascript method of posting and updating elements on the page without loading the whole webpage again is called AJAX.

If you are so keen on not learning Javascript you can use the [PHPLiveX](http://www.phplivex.com/) library to use AJAX in PHP. It's good but once you use it, you might realise why it's more practical to use Javascript. I would use [JQuery](http://jquery.com), but that is written in Javascript.

Comment: Alright then, looks like I am learning jquery! thanks for the reply, I knew that php is server side only but I guess it didnt occur to me that would make this impossible.